# If the union of infinite sequences of countable sets is countable, then how is the set of subsets of the rational numbers uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Rudin's book and this won't quite click for me. On one hand, you can prove quite easily that the set of subsets of rational numbers is uncountable (almost like cantor's diagonal argument.) On the other hand the union of infinite sequences of countable sets is countable. But the set of subsets of rational numbers is just the union of subsets of rational numbers with cardinality n, for all natural numbers n. So it should be countable, but it clearly isn't. I'm confused, can someone explain please?

Comment: Union of a *countable* sequence of countable sets is countable.

Comment: The subset $\{1, \frac12, \frac13, \frac14, \ldots\}\subset\mathbb{Q}$ isn't in any of the subsets of rational numbers of cardinality $n$, so it can't be in their union; it's not true that 'the set of subsets of rationals is the union of subsets with cardinality $n$', and that's where you're getting tripped up. Indeed, the set of _finite_ subsets of the rationals — which _is_ the union of all of the subsets of cardinality $n$ over the natural numbers $n$ — _is_ countable.

Comment: There are only countably many *finite* sets of rationals. It's when you throw in all the infinite sets of rationals that you get an uncountable collection.

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks!

Comment: The *countable union* of *countable sets* is countable. *Usually* a sequence has a countable domain/indexing set. So how many different subsets of rational numbers do you think there might be? Countably many or uncountably many?

Comment: @MattAPelto Uncountably many, because of an argument similar to cantor's diagonal argument. I think what confused me was that the cardinality of the subsets aren't  countable.

Answer (score 0):

For every real number $r$ there is a sequence of all distinct rationals $q_n(r)$ that converges to $r$.

So there are at least as many sequences in $\Bbb Q$ (and infinite subsets of $\Bbb Q$) as there are reals. So uncountably many.

A *countable* union of countable subsets is countable, but that's another unrelated fact.